# Single Grep with regex or a multiple simple greps

Tags: regex, logging, grep

I am going to be working with Grep for looking into a very large dataset. Pretty much a lot of logs. I am not sure is it better to grep it once using some sometimes crazy complex regex, or try to do a few simple grep calls and return a smaller and smaller dataset each time. I am not the best at regex but I will be able to store the regex I would need in the log searching tool, I am just looking for which method could be best.

Edit:

Sorry I forgot to add in that info it was in my last post for a different grep question. The files are logs, They could be small or large the one i am testing with is 1.9gb so far So i think that is a pretty decent size to think about, the thing is the logs will start of small and then they will grow and the logs will roate at some point lets say everyday, but If i am doing like my Apache access logs and I grep for how often the home page was loaded, or grep for the page load times so i can make an average.

Comment: Please be more specific. How large are the log files? Can you give us an idea of what you're looking for? As it stands, this question is quite unanswerable.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I have updated the question to make it more ansiwerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your dataset is quite large, it would be preferable to invoke `grep` only once with the right regex. This would avoid excessive IO overhead.

Comment: @StephaneRouberolk Lets say once i do the first grep i keep a list of the the return in memory so the follow grep's are done in memeory and not from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 'crazy regex', it may be better to build a hash of what you're looking for and then loop through your large dataset once looking for elements in the hash. I would use Perl, Python or Ruby, not grep.

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could set a list of patterns and grep for that list of patterns. This would be better than using 'crazy regex'. You could try `grep -f patterns.txt datafile.txt`.

Comment: I am using Ruby for the programming Language behind the control panel, I just using grep because its a super fast way to search a text file.

Comment: @WojonsTech: Your grep method will be super slow if the file your searching through is really big. 2 GB is not particularly big by today's standards.

Comment: I know 2gb is not big by todays standaers, what your you recommend over grep for something of that size. I was planning on building a hash on some information, it will pretty much turn into a sudo database, but i was going to go though my hash/index using grep also.

Comment: @WojonsTech: Search through a hash using grep? Why? Assuming you have built a hash of search phrases, you can do something like: `print unless $phrases{$_}`

Comment: what i mean grep the hash as in i would save the hash onto the file system for later use and i can grep that, thats what i meant by having an index.

Comment: @WojonsTech: Essentially that hash is a list of patterns. You can do this nicely with grep if your files are not too big. See the update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16824/discussion-between-wojonstech-and-steve)

Comment: I agree with you but if i have to build the hash on every lots of page loads or if i run out of memeory, thats why i was thinking of outputting an index like to the file system and than greping that also